# Getting a closed beta site w/ FB only Login to work with a Launchrock launding page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Working on implementing a new landing page for my site www.goodtogoout.com. We're about to make some changes to the staging site gtgo-staging.heroku.com which we'll then push to production, but I'm thinking of switching to FB only login and doing a closed beta while still collecting emails from interested parties via Launchrock. I'm wondering if anyone can offer any advice or help for keeping a site closed while still using the Open Graph for login / registration. Want to be able to pass along some comprehensive advice to my developer or hear something that might dissuade me from this idea.

Thanks in advance for all of your help.

Comment: This question will be better received at http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers as they tend to answer more of the admin related questions like this one.  On stackoverflow we like to answer programming code related questions.